# How to create an image slideshow in a Vaadin Spring Boot Web application?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, vaadin

I am new to Vaadin and Spring Boot. I've built the project with Maven. I have tried to create an image slideshow in many different ways, but all got me to endless issues/errors.

I want to create an web app with fake ads as it is just a school project and I will not publish it. I need the slideshow in order to replicate the ads effects.

I've tried to implement this by threads, fancylayouts add-on from Vaadin, Swing Timers, scheduled tasks with Spring etc.

```
https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/
https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/fancylayouts
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html
```

What is the most suitable way to do this?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

If it helps, here is my last attempt:

```
package com.example.ui;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.vaadin.server.Resource;
import com.vaadin.server.ThemeResource;
import com.vaadin.ui.Image;
import com.vaadin.ui.Layout;

@Component
public class Ads {
    Image image;
    int i;
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Ads.class);

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
    public void AdsImg() {

    Resource res = new ThemeResource("images/"+i+".jpg");
    image = new Image(null, res);

}

public Ads() {

    for (int i=1; i<=4;i++){    
        AdsImg();

    }


 }
}
```

Comment: Just curious, is Vaadin a requirement or were you just trying it out?

Comment: I need to do a project that is at my discretion what technologies I use (I was trying it out.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples-custom)

You can easily create a Carousel using the most popular UI framework, **Bootstrap**.

On their examples page they have one specifically called [Carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/).  Open this example, view the HTML source and you can then customize it and make it your own.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I haven't managed to figure it out how to ingrate the html block of code into java. Can you please give me an example?

Comment: For static webpages like this, you only need a very simple setup.  You need the spring-boot-starter-web dependency, a main Java class annotated with @SpringBootApplication, and the webpage placed in src/main/resources/static  Here is a full working example: https://github.com/kanderson450/stackoverflow-q41048936

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The thing is, I am doing a dynamic website. Now, my only concern is how to integrate the html content into the java classes.

Comment: Help me understand what you're trying to accomplish. Then I can give a specific recommendation.

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to insert the html block of code into a java class in order to create the carousel thing with bootstrap.

Comment: I figure it out how to insert the html code into the java class. I used `CustomLayout custom2 = new CustomLayout("trycarusel");` and added the trycarusel.html file to src\main\webapp\VAADIN\themes\colored\layouts